# How to customize the Facebook Like Button Message

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I'm following the advise of FB's tutorial here and I even used their open graph generator:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

but my like message does not use this data.  It uses outdated info from the site that I've changed awhile ago.

I've just added my open graph tags and they look like this:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Test Title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="activity" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://foo.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://foo.com/images/image.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Foo" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Hey, check out this thing" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="Foo" />
```

And yet when I enter my site into Linter, it says I'm missing all the required meta tags (title, type url, etc).

It says it takes 24 hours to scrape so maybe I just need to wait but it also said that if I enter my site into Linter that it'll work right away.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run your url through the [linter](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) it will automatically scrape your page and update facebook's cache with your new OG tags. If you're not seeing this behavior, it's either a bug or you're not entering the exact url where your page exists containing these OG tags, or your like button references an outdated URL.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was that the I had to enter the URL of the current page into the actual like button tag.  The Facebook docs claimed that if you left that blank it would default to the current page but that seemed to not work.  Once I entered in the URL by hand, everything started working.